Xremap can't prepare an output device
Initially to emulate my work environment of MacOS I tried juggling gsettings, gnome tweaks, changing shortcuts, changing fn_mode, changing IntelliJ shortcuts, terminal shortcuts... then i saw this all in one xremap solution and tried to make it function:
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh

cargo install xremap --features gnome

update /usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf with allow user line (yes I know):
<policy context="default">
<allow user="root"/>
sudo gpasswd -a YOUR_USER input

echo 'KERNEL=="uinput", GROUP="input", TAG+="uaccess"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/input.rules

busctl --user call org.gnome.Shell /com/k0kubun/Xremap com.k0kubun.Xremap WMClasses

I type in terminal xremap .config/xremap-config.yml
RETURNS
Error: Failed to prepare an output device: Permission denied (os error 13)

(I have cut a few steps out)
What am I missing?
